# Is it possible to 'upgrade' a 5V-RC-servo for higher voltages?

Tags: dc-motor, servo

I built a robot using [these servos](https://www.banggood.com/SPT-Servo-SPT4412LV-12KG-Digital-Servo-Large-Torque-Metal-Gear-Short-Body-For-RC-Airplane-Car-Boat-p-1382838.html?utm_design=41&utm_source=emarsys&utm_medium=Shipoutinform171129&utm_campaign=trigger-emarsys&utm_content=Winna&sc_src=email_2671705&sc_eh=a7664846f744ca791&sc_llid=11489110&sc_lid=104858042&sc_uid=PAubBDJ9Hu&cur_warehouse=CN). Since the robot is quite heavy, the motors need more current than my power supply is capable to deliver (around 3.5A peak).

One solution would be to upgrade the power supply or get a second one. But the solution I would prefer is limiting the current by raising the voltage.

I opened one of the servos and saw that they are made of a DC-motor, a gearbox, a potentiometer and a microcontroller. Is it possible to replace the control unit with another one? Being inexperienced in analogue stuff, I do not know much about motos. Can I lower their current consumption by raising the voltage at the motor or at least at the control electronics?

Comment: How many of these motors are you planning on having? According to this seller's specs, there's a blocking current of 1.8A. So if you have two more motors that has something that prevents the motors from moving, it could really bust your your power supply.

Comment: I got 12 of them.

Comment: Then I would recommend that you get a power supply that can provide more current draw :) If you're unaware, blocking current is the amount of current that is drawn when a motor stalls. I'm not much of a motor or analog person (as my career mainly deals with digital electronics) but memory serves me correctly, if you hold a motor and prevent it from moving, that's when the blocking current is determined. If something gets jammed or you programmed your motors incorrectly, you can say goodbye to that power supply.

Comment: If you have 12 motors then I'd suggest getting a power supply that provides 1.8×12=21.6A, maybe a little more. This will help you prepare for the worst case scenario where if all of your motors are jammed all at once.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but actually this solution is one I'm trying to avoid. I would rather modify the servos instead of getting another power supply. :)

Comment: No, modifying the servos would involve new electronics and a new motor. aka another servo. PWM curent limiting doesnt work the way you think it does.

Comment: Then if you're looking for different servos, make sure it provides a viable torque and/or rotation speed for your solution, though I think you're being a little too strict on your 3.5A current draw rule. You're wanting something more powerful yet keeping the maximum current draw the same. Due to the laws of physics in our universe, I don't think you'll find a motor that can draw the same amount of current yet provides a higher torque or rotation speed unless, by some miracle, you find a magnetic core of a different material.

Comment: What you are proposing doesn't make sense. Increasing the voltage while lowering the current doesn't change the total power required by the system.

Comment: As I said, I haven't much experience in hardware. I thought motors work according to P = U*I, thus raising the voltage and keeping the power constant would decrease the current.

Comment: @Schnopop *subject to other factors such as regearing or using a different winding of the motor. your current limiting drive is not the same as a true current regulating drive and there is not enough room in a rc servo for that. not to mention it would be much more expensive than just buying higher voltage servos like the very expensive dynamixels

Comment: Why are you so concerned with lowering the current?  A higher current supply will be _by far_ the easier solution here.  You are not going to be able to modify those servos with out going to ridiculous lengths.

Comment: @evildemonic What do you mean by "ridiculous lengths"? 

Actually, you are right, the easiest solution would be to take another supply and maybe increase the lead diameter. My problem here is that once the robot works, I want to equip it with some batteries and run it non-stationary. Is it possible to run such an high-current-setup with batteries?

Comment: you need to give us details on your robot before we can answer that question. otherwise i could just start talking about electric airplanes that use 140A motors that run on batteries. with no sense of scale, weight, or power your question is impossible to answer. Example: a nuclear reactor works great on a carrier. not so much on a canoe.

Comment: @Schnopop I mean that while technically _possible_ it will be far far more work than could possibly be worthwhile.

Comment: What details do you need? It is a quadruped robot, a small version of this one: [link](https://images.app.goo.gl/DJVSCcJ3a23ULdMY6). Each leg is equipped with three servos, one for each joint. Moving forward is not a problem, but standing up (moving the body from ground to operating hight) is.

Comment: how much does that thing weigh without batteries and how much weight can it support? you might need to work out  the torque and leverage limits at the most loaded joint as well as the minimum number of driving legs in the worst case motion

Comment: A car battery could certainly supply that kind of current, but we don't know how much weight your robot can support for the batteries.

Comment: @DKNguyen 2.1kg

Comment: you are going to need lithium polymer batteries.  A 2 cell, 3 amp hour capacity should be able to provide sufficient current assuming 12C to 15C maximum current draw. most motors should not  be staled under normal operation so you could go a bit smaller to reduce weight. but for best efficiency you run direct off the batteries and those motors cant run off 7.4V so you will need regulators such as rc model BECs. Next time, design from the start with power supply in mind. You dont design a car or plane with the engines and fuel as an after thought

Comment: Thanks @KingDuken, I will look for the setup you proposed. 

If we could turn back time, what would change in the design process?

Comment: id like to move this to discussion later when i have access to a real keyboard. unlike wheels, legs makes it more akin to aircraft design in that weight matters a lot more as do the specific types of motion/movements involved. both need to be determined and evaluated against existing actuators and power sources (and the weight of those components). That needs to happen very early on since its the hardest thing to change and to determine if things are even feasible. its completely possible to end up with a robot that cant move itself

Comment: BTW if your robot cant get up at 2.1kg and that is the non battery weight (I assume the current power supply isnt onboard) you will need to make changes. probably by increasing the size or doubling up the motors at the most loaded joints or shifting some weightoff the main body down onto the lower legs. our calves arent the size of our hamstrings for a reason, after all. or maybe springs at the loaded joint to preload things in the opposite direction a bit

Comment: @Schnopop There's too much to consider. The dynamics of your robot, the weight of your robot, the mechanical structure of your robot, the degrees of freedom your robot needs, what microcontroller you wish to use, the electrical characteristics of your robot, and a lot more. You're giving yourself too much work. If you ever written scripts before, you know that you can't simply dive into writing until you have some type of algorithm and plan of action. You have to think about what you need and how it will cooperate with other factors. Engineering is time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does raising the supply voltage lower the maximum current on my servo?

Short answer, NO.

It's somewhat more nuanced than that of course:

The servo you have is is rated at 6V and designed to limit **stall current** to 1.8A,
You could raise your power supply voltage from 5V to 6V, but the servo will still stall limit at the same 1.8A. Your servo is designed to supply a large torque, and you don't explain just how much mechanical effort is required in your application, so there is no way to judge what your operating current should be.The operating current will be only that which supplies the torque you require from the servo at any given instant.

The mechanical effort required and speed interact in any servo design, so you could lower the operating current requirement for your servo (under your particular mechanical load) by increasing the gear ratio. This would lower the torque (and hence current) required, but would also lower the speed of response for the system. For example if you geared down the output by 2:1 (or shortened the arc lever in half) you would lower the operating current required by half but double the time taken to travel a given arc.

You should also check that you are not running into a hard mechanical stop at the extremities of your mechanical motion. You should never command your servo beyond its mechanical limit as this will obviously trigger the stall current limit. Typically any current limit set is well above the operating current of the servo to supply its rated torque.

The amount of energy you need to carry on/in your platform to power your robot for a given time will NOT change if you raise the voltage of your battery pack. The number of W/kg for batteries is almost constant, so the weight of your pack would not change, so most of this reorganization is a zero sum game.

Comment: "designed to limit stall current to 1.8A" - actually the stall current is often only limited by motor and H-bridge resistance. At higher voltage it will probably draw more current, operate faster, and burn out the motor and/or controller if worked hard. At some voltage the controller will blow up due to over-voltage.

Comment: @BruceAbbott I agree for analog servos,but not for digital servos, they are actively limited.

Answer (score 0):

What you are wanting to do doesn't actually make sense.

Your power supply can deliver some maximum amount of power. We can write that as a current at some voltage or as watts.

Let's say you have a 12V supply with 3.5A peak. That is 42 watts your supply can give you. Now let's raise the supply voltage to 24V and halve the current to 1.75A. That's still 42 watts.

So if your load requires say 50 watts, your supply cannot deliver this power no matter how much you increase your voltage while lowering your current. You can only get 42 watts out of it.

The only solutions are to either reduce the power required by your load or increase the power available at your supply.

There are many good reasons to use a higher voltage with a lower current, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: It is a current regulated supply. It can deliver up to 700W, but the current control works for a maximum current of 3.5A, regardless of the set voltage. Thus the maximum power it can deliver at 5V is 175W.

Comment: @Schnopop okay, well that's an important piece of info you should add to your question :p Also if you're planning to switch to batteries this will not be a problem. I really think you should just use a different supply.

Comment: @Schnopop:  You seem to be out by a factor of 10 in stating the power supply capability.  3.5 Amp @ 5 V = 17.5 watts, not 175.